# Bending wood, how do I know it is far enough?

Tags: boats, wooden

Am building a Frisian schouw, I have oakwood and build a frame on which the wood can rest. How would I know the wood has bend enough and how serious would it be if it is bend to far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I built my canoe, the front and back keel stems needed to be bent. I steamed the wood by putting it in some ABS pipe and putting that over a kettle. It's been over 25 years, but I think there was cloth stuffed at the top of the pipe to keep the steam in, or something like that. I left the wood steaming until it was warm and soft, and then clamped it in place on the form. If I couldn't get the wood to bend against the form, I put it back in the pipe to steam some more. Once I could clamp it right againt the form, I let it cool, and then carried on with the building process.

If you try to bend the wood when it's not soft enough it will break. Is that what you mean by "how serious would it be if it is bent too far?"

Comment: 'too far': if the curve is too far bend. Am trying to construct the thing in my mind first but can't find much about the subject.

Comment: But if I read you good, you soften it up and then you push it against the form and somehow secure it to be left to dry/cool and then let it takes it form. Makes more sense then my first thought.